# Stop current thread until the called thread is finished then continue it

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, deadlock

Let's say I have these two methods and they keep calling each other:

```
public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Thread " +
                    Thread.currentThread().getId() +
                    " is running");
            posses(numberOfPlayers, players);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception Caught");
        }
    }

synchronized public void posses(int n, Players[] players) throws InterruptedException {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            if (players[i].haveBall)
                System.out.println("Player" + i + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println(" \bhave the ball now");

        for (int i = 1; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
            if (players[i].haveBall) {
                System.out.println("\nList of available players to pass for player " + i + ": ");
                for (int j = 1; j < numberOfPlayers; j++) {
                    if (players[j].isActive && j != i) {
                        System.out.println("Player " + players[j].number);
                    }
                }

                System.out.println();

                do {
                    receiver = rand.nextInt(numberOfPlayers - 1) + 1;
                } while (i == receiver && players[receiver].isActive);

                if (players[receiver].haveBall) {
                    System.out.println("Player" + i + " passes");
                    System.out.println("Player" + receiver + " receives");

                    players[receiver].start();
                    players[i].join(2000);

                    players[i].haveBall = false;
                    players[receiver].haveBall = true;
                    players[receiver].players = players[0].players;
                    ;

                    System.out.println();

                    for (int p = 1; p < n; p++) {
                        System.out.println(players[p].haveBall);
                    }

                } else {
                    players[i].haveBall = false;
                    System.out.println("Player" + i + " passes");
                    players[receiver].haveBall = true;
                    System.out.println(players[receiver].number + " receives");
                    players[receiver].players = players[0].players;

                    System.out.println();

                    for (int p = 1; p < n; p++) {
                        System.out.println(players[p].haveBall);
                    }

                    players[receiver].start();
                }
            }
        }
```

this is a football team which we have two balls and each player can have maximum number of one ball. these players pass balls randomly under the condition that they can not pass the ball to a player that currently has a ball.
I have a for-loop here which loops through players and choose the ones who have balls and make them to pass it.
what I want to do is that if the player that we want to pass to, has a ball, wait until he passes the ball, then pass the ball to him. but the join() method for threads which I wrote does not work this way.(consider every player is a thread). what is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a shared resource accessible to all worker threads, once a thread picks a resource he does the work with that resource , when ever he is done he returns the resource to the shared resource pool.

for example a ball queue  , players query the queue to check if there is ball available, on picking up a ball they do the work with the ball , then put it back in the queue. this guarantees the basic requirement of 1 ball per player at a time.

Couple of more things to consider :

- thread starvation , a player does not touch the ball . one way to handle this is to put the thread to sleep after a player has picked up ball.
- this example is polling approach  of a shared resource easy to implement how ever you do "wast" cycles where a thread checks if a resource becomes available can be very wasteful in a scenario where you have 1 ball to 1M players  similarly there can be push approach that reduce that waste.